# How to write a generic method to built a list of data with common interface?

Tags: c#

We are going to use compressed json string for storing / passing the configuration data in our system.

We have added two methods fromJson and toJson in the interface (IData) of all data class.  And we have built a generic method to convert a list of such data to json as below:

```
public static dynamic List2Json(List<IData> data)
{
  List<dynamic> json = new List<dynamic>();
  foreach(IData o in data)
  {
    json.Add(o.toJson());
  }
  return json;
}
```

But there has problem to build similar method to convert the json array back to the list.  We cannot create an object for a interface. (i.e. IData x = new IData();) Or even we create a base class, we still cannot do it in this way.

```
public void Json2List(ref List<IData> list, DynamicJsonArray json)
{
  list = new List<IData>();
  foreach(dynamic o in json)
  {
    IData x = new IData();
    x.fromJson(o);
    list.Add(x);
  }
}
```

We also tried the Generic Methods as below, but still we cannot create the object by T x = new T();

```
public void Json2List<T>(ref List<T> data, dynamic json) where T : IData
{
  data = new List<T>();
  foreach(dynamic o in json)
  {
    T x = new T();
    x.fromJson(o);
    data.Add(o);
  }
}
```

We also think about the other way to return the new instance by a static method of the data class.  But unfortunately, static method is not supported in interface, and static method in base class cannot be override.  So we still need a instance of that class in order to create another instance.  Finally, we make a stupid way that require a instance of required class as parameter, and use this dummy instance to generate all instance of the list.

```
  public interface IData
  {
    IData createFromJson(dynamic json);
    dynamic toJson();
  }

  public abstract class baseData : IData
  {
    public virtual IData objectFromJson(dynamic json, baseData source)
    {
      return source.createFromJson(json);
    }
    public abstract IData createFromJson(dynamic json); 
  }

  public static void Json2List<T>(ref List<T> data, dynamic json, baseData source) where T : IData
  {
    data = new List<T>();
    foreach(dynamic o in json)
    {
      data.Add(source.objectFromJson(o, source));
    }
  }

  public class a : baseData
  {
    public override IData createFromJson(dynamic json)
    {
      a object = new a();
      // assign the value to object from json here
      return object;
    }
  }

  // in the program need to convert from json
  //
  dynamic json = ... // json object containing required data
  List<a> list = new List<a>();  
  Json2List(ref list, json, new a());
```

Now it works, but it need to create a dummy object in calling the method.

i.e.  Json2List(ref list, json, **new a()**); in above example.  It's really dummy and we only need this instance for calling the createFromJson method.

May I know if there has any way to improve the program, so that there has no need to build a dummy object in this way?

Comment: What are you using to do the actual serialization? Json.Net?

Comment: And, is there a reason you are resorting to dynamic instead of Object? What is the "dynamic" json anyway?

Comment: If interface's methods return `dynamic` or take `dynamic` as argument probably the classes that implement the interface doesn't have nothing in common.

Comment: I just use the Json class in System.Web.Helpers.  It's mainly for serialization at this moment, we have try to serialization the object itself, but it will cause problem later when we modify the class definition (e.g. some new elements added), it may not be able to read the existing data file.  Moreover, some data comes from the web service which is in json string format.  So, we choose to use Json when passing data in our application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible with a combination of generics and the new() clause in where. The latter tells the compiler to allow new on generic type. You have to make sure that generic type has a constructor without parameters.

```
public void Json2List<T>(...) where T : IData, new()
{
  data = new T() as IData;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just try to modify the code, but there has another issue.
If data is the defined as T, then data = new T() as IData;  will cause error.
But if data is defined as IData, it will have error when I attempt to add it to the list.  
Should I just define data as IData, then add type casting when adding to the list?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works find by using IData for data, and then cast to T when adding to the list.  We only need to make sure all data class do have a constructor without parameter.
It seems that we cannot define a constructor in the interface or base class.  But anyway, it's better than repeating the same code for every class.